# How can I do that without settimeout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux-saga

When I press onLike button I want to dispatch the load process

I want to see LOAD_POST_SUCCESS right after LIKE_POST_SUCESS

When I press onLike button I want to dispatch the load process

I want to see LOAD_POST_SUCCESS right after LIKE_POST_SUCESS

Like this:

[image]

but sometimes the process is unreliable

like this:

[image]

```
                import React, { useEffect, useState,useCallback } from 'react';
                import styled from 'styled-components/native';
                import {LOAD_POST_REQUEST,LIKE_POST_REQUEST, UNLIKE_POST_REQUEST, INITIAL_REQUEST,COOK_UP_REQUEST} from '../../../reducers/post';
                import {useDispatch,useSelector} from 'react-redux';
                import {
                RetweetOutlined, HeartOutlined, MessageOutlined, EllipsisOutlined, HeartTwoTone,
                } from '@ant-design/icons';
                import IconButton from '../../components/IconButton';
                import { ImageBackground } from 'react-native';

                const Container = styled.View`

                `; 
                const Hi = styled.Text`

                `;
                const IconButtonU = styled.Image`
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
                `;

                const LikeNumber = styled.Text`

                `;
                const MenuContainer = styled.TouchableOpacity`
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
                `;


                const Explain = ({navigation,route}) => {

                const dispatch = useDispatch();

                const {me} = useSelector((state) =>state.user);
                const {singlePost} = useSelector((state) => state.post);


                const onLike = () => {
                return dispatch({
                     type: LIKE_POST_REQUEST,
                     data: singlePost?.id,
                }),

                dispatch({
                     type: LOAD_POST_REQUEST,
                     data:singlePost.id
                     })

                }


                const onUnlike = () => {
                return dispatch({
                     type: UNLIKE_POST_REQUEST,
                     data: singlePost?.id,
                }),

                dispatch({
                     type: LOAD_POST_REQUEST,
                     data:singlePost.id
                     })

                }



                const liked = singlePost?.Likers.find((v) => v.id === me?.id);

                return (
                <Container>
                <Hi>
                     안녕
                </Hi>


                {  liked       
                ?  
                <MenuContainer  onPress={onUnlike}  >
                <IconButtonU iconName="favorite"
                     style={{width:23, height:23}}
                     source={require('../../Assets/Images/Tabs/heart.png')}
                     />
                </MenuContainer>
                :   
                <MenuContainer  onPress={onLike}  >
                <IconButtonU iconName="favorite"
                     source={require('../../Assets/Images/Tabs/ic_favorite_outline.png')}
                     />
                     </MenuContainer>
                     }


                <LikeNumber>
                좋아요{' '}
                {singlePost?.Likers.length }
                </LikeNumber>


                </Container>

                );
                };

                export default Explain;
```

(saga/post.js)

```
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { all, fork, put, takeLatest, throttle, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';

    import {

      ADD_POST_FAILURE,
      ADD_POST_REQUEST,
      ADD_POST_SUCCESS,
      
      LOAD_POST_FAILURE,
      LOAD_POST_REQUEST,
      LOAD_POST_SUCCESS,

      LOAD_POSTS_FAILURE,
      LOAD_POSTS_REQUEST,
      LOAD_POSTS_SUCCESS, 

      LOAD_USER_POSTS_FAILURE, 
      LOAD_USER_POSTS_REQUEST, 
      LOAD_USER_POSTS_SUCCESS,

      COOK_UP_REQUEST,
      COOK_UP_SUCCESS,
      COOK_UP_FAILURE,
      
      UPLOAD_IMAGES_FAILURE,
      UPLOAD_IMAGES_REQUEST,
      UPLOAD_IMAGES_SUCCESS,

      LIKE_POST_FAILURE,
      LIKE_POST_REQUEST,
      LIKE_POST_SUCCESS,

      UNLIKE_POST_FAILURE,
      UNLIKE_POST_REQUEST,
      UNLIKE_POST_SUCCESS,

      FLFOOD_UP_REQUEST,
      FLFOOD_UP_SUCCESS,
      FLFOOD_UP_FAILURE,

      DELETE_FLFOOD_UP_REQUEST,
      DELETE_FLFOOD_UP_SUCCESS,
      DELETE_FLFOOD_UP_FAILURE,

      ADD_COMMENT_FAILURE,
      ADD_COMMENT_REQUEST,
      ADD_COMMENT_SUCCESS,

      INITIAL_FAILURE, 
      INITIAL_REQUEST, 
      INITIAL_SUCCESS,

      REMOVE_POST_FAILURE,
      REMOVE_POST_REQUEST,
      REMOVE_POST_SUCCESS,

      UPDATE_POST_FAILURE,
      UPDATE_POST_REQUEST,
      UPDATE_POST_SUCCESS,

      LOAD_HASHTAG_POSTS_FAILURE,
      LOAD_HASHTAG_POSTS_REQUEST,
      LOAD_HASHTAG_POSTS_SUCCESS,

      REMOVE_COMMENT_FAILURE,
      REMOVE_COMMENT_REQUEST,
      REMOVE_COMMENT_SUCCESS,

      EDIT_COMMENT_FAILURE,
      EDIT_COMMENT_REQUEST,
      EDIT_COMMENT_SUCCESS,

    } from '../reducers/post';
    import { ADD_POST_TO_ME, REMOVE_POST_OF_ME } from '../reducers/user';


    function uploadImagesAPI(data) {
      return axios.post('/post/images', data);
    }

    function* uploadImages(action) {
      try {
        const result = yield call(uploadImagesAPI, action.data);
        yield put({
          type: UPLOAD_IMAGES_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        yield put({
          type: UPLOAD_IMAGES_FAILURE,
          error: err.response.data,
        });
      }
    }

    function likePostAPI(data) {
      return axios.patch(`/post/${data}/like`);
    }

    function* likePost(action) {
      try {
        const result = yield call(likePostAPI, action.data);
        yield put({
          type: LIKE_POST_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        yield put({
          type: LIKE_POST_FAILURE,
          error: err.response.data,
        });
      }
    }

    function unlikePostAPI(data) {
      return axios.delete(`/post/${data}/like`);
    }

    function* unlikePost(action) {
      try {
        const result = yield call(unlikePostAPI, action.data);
        yield put({
          type: UNLIKE_POST_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        yield put({
          type: UNLIKE_POST_FAILURE,
          error: err.response.data,
        });
      }
    }



    function loadPostAPI(data) {
      return axios.get(`/post/${data}`);
    }

    function* loadPost(action) {
      try {
        const result = yield call(loadPostAPI, action.data);
        yield put({
          type: LOAD_POST_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        yield put({
          type: LOAD_POST_FAILURE,
          error: err.response.data,
        });
      }
    }


    function loadUserPostsAPI(data, lastId) {
    
      return axios.get(`/posts/my/postss?lastId=${lastId || 0}`);
    }


    function* loadUserPosts(action) {
      try {
    
        const result = yield call(loadUserPostsAPI, action.data, action.lastId);
        yield put({
          type: LOAD_USER_POSTS_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        yield put({
          type: LOAD_USER_POSTS_FAILURE,
          error: err.response.data,
        });
      }
    }

    function loadPostsAPI(lastId) {
      return axios.get(`/posts?lastId=${lastId || 0}`);
    }

    function* loadPosts(action) {
      try {
        const result = yield call(loadPostsAPI, action.lastId);
        yield put({
          type: LOAD_POSTS_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        yield put({
          type: LOAD_POSTS_FAILURE,
          error: err.response.data,
        });
      }
    }



    function cookUpAPI(data, lastId) {
      return axios.post(`/posts/cookup/postss?lastId=${lastId || 0}`, data);
    }

    function* cookupPost(action) {
      try {
        const result = yield call(cookUpAPI, action.data, action.lastId);
        yield put({
          type: COOK_UP_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        yield put({
          type: COOK_UP_FAILURE,
          error: err.response.data,
        });
      }
    }

    function flfoodUpAPI(data) {
      
      return axios.get('/posts/related', data);
    }

    function* flfoodPost(action) {
      try {
        const result = yield call(flfoodUpAPI, action.data);
        yield put({
          type: FLFOOD_UP_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        yield put({
          type: FLFOOD_UP_FAILURE,
          error: err.response.data,
        });
      }
    }


    function* DeleteflfoodPost(action) {
      try {
        const result = action.data;
        yield put({
          type: DELETE_FLFOOD_UP_SUCCESS,
          data: result,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        yield put({
          type: DELETE_FLFOOD_UP_FAILURE,
          error: err.response.data,
        });
      }
    }

    function addPostAPI(action) {
      return axios.post('/post', action);
    }

    function* addPost(action) {
      try {
        const result = yield call(addPostAPI, action);
        yield put({
          type: ADD_POST_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
        yield put({
          type: ADD_POST_TO_ME,
          data: result.data.id,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        yield put({
          type: ADD_POST_FAILURE,
          error: err.response.data,
        });
      }
    }


    function addCommentAPI(data) {
      return axios.post(`/post/${data.postId}/comment`, data); // POST /post/1/comment
    }

    function* addComment(action) {
      try {
        const result = yield call(addCommentAPI, action.data);
        yield put({
          type: ADD_COMMENT_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        yield put({
          type: ADD_COMMENT_FAILURE,
          error: err.response.data,
        });
      }
    }



    function* intial(action) {
      try {
        const result = [];
        yield put({
          type: INITIAL_SUCCESS,
          data: result,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        yield put({
          type: INITIAL_FAILURE,
          error: err.response.data,
        });
      }
    }

    function removePostAPI(data) {
      return axios.delete(`/post/${data}`);
    }

    function* removePost(action) {
      try {
        const result = yield call(removePostAPI, action.data);
        yield put({
          type: REMOVE_POST_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
        yield put({
          type: REMOVE_POST_OF_ME,
          data: action.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        yield put({
          type: REMOVE_POST_FAILURE,
          error: err.response.data,
        });
      }
    }



    function updatePostAPI(data) {
      return axios.patch(`/post/${data.PostId}`, data);
    }

    function* updatePost(action) {
      try {
      
        const result = yield call(updatePostAPI, action.data);
        console.log("result:",result);
        yield put({
          type: UPDATE_POST_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        yield put({
          type: UPDATE_POST_FAILURE,
          error: err.response.data,
        });
      }
    }

    function loadHashtagPostsAPI(data, lastId) {
      return axios.get(`/hashtag/${encodeURIComponent(data)}?lastId=${lastId || 0}`);
    }

    function* loadHashtagPosts(action) {
      try {
        console.log("action:::",action);
        console.log('loadHashtag console');
        const result = yield call(loadHashtagPostsAPI, action.data, action.lastId);
        yield put({
          type: LOAD_HASHTAG_POSTS_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        yield put({
          type: LOAD_HASHTAG_POSTS_FAILURE,
          error: err.response.data,
        });
      }
    }



    function commentremovePostAPI(data) {
      return axios.post(`/post/removecomment/`,data);
    }

    function* commentremovePost(action) {
      try {
        const result = yield call(commentremovePostAPI, action.data);
        yield put({
          type: REMOVE_COMMENT_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        yield put({
          type: REMOVE_COMMENT_FAILURE,
          error: err.response.data,
        });
      }
    }




    function EditCommenPostAPI(data) {
      return axios.patch(`/post/editcomment/`,data);
    }

    function* EditCommentPosts(action) {
      try {
        //  console.log("action:",action);
        const result = yield call(EditCommenPostAPI, action.data);
        console.log("result:::",result);
        yield put({
          type:EDIT_COMMENT_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        yield put({
          type: EDIT_COMMENT_FAILURE,
          error: err.response.data,
        });
      }
    }








    function* watchUploadImages() {
      yield takeLatest(UPLOAD_IMAGES_REQUEST, uploadImages);
    }


    function* watchLoadPost() {
      yield takeLatest(LOAD_POST_REQUEST, loadPost);
    }

    function* watchLikePost() {
      yield takeLatest(LIKE_POST_REQUEST, likePost);
    }

    function* watchUnlikePost() {
      yield takeLatest(UNLIKE_POST_REQUEST, unlikePost);
    }

    function* watchAddPost() {
      yield takeLatest(ADD_POST_REQUEST, addPost);
    }

    function* watchLoadUserPosts() {
      yield throttle(5000, LOAD_USER_POSTS_REQUEST, loadUserPosts);
    }

    function* watchLoadPosts() {
      yield throttle(5000, LOAD_POSTS_REQUEST, loadPosts);
    }

    function* watchCookupPosts() {
      yield throttle(1000, COOK_UP_REQUEST, cookupPost);
    }

    function* watchFlfoodupPosts() {
      yield throttle(5000, FLFOOD_UP_REQUEST, flfoodPost);
    }

    function* watchDeleteFlfoodupPosts() {
      yield throttle(5000, DELETE_FLFOOD_UP_REQUEST, DeleteflfoodPost);
    }

    function* watchAddComment() {
      yield takeLatest(ADD_COMMENT_REQUEST, addComment);
    }

    function* watchintial() {
      yield takeLatest(INITIAL_REQUEST, intial);
    }


    function* watchRemovePost() {
      yield takeLatest(REMOVE_POST_REQUEST, removePost);
    }


    function* watchUpdatePost() {
      yield takeLatest(UPDATE_POST_REQUEST, updatePost);
    }

    function* watchLoadHashtagPosts() {
      yield throttle(5000, LOAD_HASHTAG_POSTS_REQUEST, loadHashtagPosts);
    }

    function* watchCommentRemovePost() {
      yield takeLatest(REMOVE_COMMENT_REQUEST, commentremovePost);
    }

    function* watchEditCommentPost() {
      yield takeLatest(EDIT_COMMENT_REQUEST, EditCommentPosts);
    }



    export default function* postSaga() {
      yield all([
        fork(watchUploadImages),
        fork(watchLikePost),
        fork(watchUnlikePost),
        fork(watchLoadPost),
        fork(watchAddPost),
        fork(watchLoadUserPosts),
        fork(watchLoadPosts),
        fork(watchCookupPosts),
        fork(watchFlfoodupPosts),
        fork(watchDeleteFlfoodupPosts),
        fork(watchAddComment),
        fork(watchintial),
        fork(watchRemovePost),
        fork(watchUpdatePost),
        fork(watchLoadHashtagPosts),
        fork(watchCommentRemovePost),
        fork(watchEditCommentPost),
      ]);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a problem with just simply dispatching the two events? Why the timeout/delay for the second? In other words, there's a code smell here and it isn't clear what problem you are really trying to solve for. Can you provide a bit of context?

Comment: is because if i rid of settimeout redux is like this LIKE_Post_Request->  Load_Post_Request -> LOAD_Post_SUCESS-> LIKE_Post_SUCESS
but i want to  LIKE_Post_Request->   LIKE_Post_SUCESS->  LOAD_Post_REQUEST->LOAD_Post_SUCESS-

Comment: I see. Does the order of the processed actions matter in the store? Do you happen to use any asynchronous action [middleware](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic#redux-middleware-and-side-effects), i.e. redux-thunk? You could write a single atomic asynchronous action that immediately dispatches the first action, and then later when you are ready, dispatch the second. This is, IMHO, a more correct/optimal solution to passing "action callback" around to chain them together.

Comment: I can, but seems it's quite related to this current issue. You should have instead really updated this question with the updated code you are working with and added the images here. It's preferable. Well. looks like it was closed before I could mark it duplicate of this one. You can add more middlewares. I think Thunks will help you here, but since we don't know what these actions need to do it's difficult to form an answer..

Comment: i did now please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sensing that these are two network calls. And the first needs to be complete before you make the second call. If this is the case, and you estimate that it would typically take 100ms to complete, this is bad practice. It makes your code unreliable. What I would do in that case is get rid of the setTimeout and send the second dispatch call as a callback function to the first dispatch. i.e.

```
const onLikeCallback = () => {
    dispatch({
        type: LIKE_POST_REQUEST,
        data: singlePost?.id,
    }) 
}

const onLike = () => {
    dispatch({
        type:LOAD_POST_REQUEST,
        data:singlePost.id,
        callback: onLikeCallback
    })
}
```

Then call action.callback() after the promise where you are making the API request resolves. i.e.

```
likeApiPromise(action.data).then(res => action.callback())
```

OR

```
await likeApiPromise(action.data)
action.callback()
```

**Edit**:
Since you're using Saga, it's even easier! All you need to do is:

```
function* likePost(action) {
      try {
        const result = yield call(likePostAPI, action.data);
        yield put({
          type: LOAD_POST_REQUEST,
          data: action.data,
        });
        yield put({
          type: LIKE_POST_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        yield put({
          type: LIKE_POST_FAILURE,
          error: err.response.data,
        });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

when i try press onLike button i want to dispatch this process i want to get LOAD_POST_SUCCESS right after LIKE_POST_SUCESS like this code

[image]

but sometimes it process unreliable

like this

[image]

import React, { useEffect, useState,useCallback } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
import {LOAD_POST_REQUEST,LIKE_POST_REQUEST, UNLIKE_POST_REQUEST, INITIAL_REQUEST,COOK_UP_REQUEST} from '../../../reducers/post';
import {useDispatch,useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {
RetweetOutlined, HeartOutlined, MessageOutlined, EllipsisOutlined, HeartTwoTone,
} from '@ant-design/icons';
import IconButton from '../../components/IconButton';
import { ImageBackground } from 'react-native';

```
            const Container = styled.View`

            `; 
            const Hi = styled.Text`

            `;
            const IconButtonU = styled.Image`
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            `;

            const LikeNumber = styled.Text`

            `;
            const MenuContainer = styled.TouchableOpacity`
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            `;


            const Explain = ({navigation,route}) => {

            const dispatch = useDispatch();

            const {me} = useSelector((state) =>state.user);
            const {singlePost} = useSelector((state) => state.post);


            const onLike = () => {
            return dispatch({
                 type: LIKE_POST_REQUEST,
                 data: singlePost?.id,
            }),
            
            dispatch({
                 type: LOAD_POST_REQUEST,
                 data:singlePost.id
                 })
            
            }
            
            
            const onUnlike = () => {
            return dispatch({
                 type: UNLIKE_POST_REQUEST,
                 data: singlePost?.id,
            }),
            
            dispatch({
                 type: LOAD_POST_REQUEST,
                 data:singlePost.id
                 })
            
            }
            
            
            
            const liked = singlePost?.Likers.find((v) => v.id === me?.id);

            return (
            <Container>
            <Hi>
                 안녕
            </Hi>


            {  liked       
            ?  
            <MenuContainer  onPress={onUnlike}  >
            <IconButtonU iconName="favorite"
                 style={{width:23, height:23}}
                 source={require('../../Assets/Images/Tabs/heart.png')}
                 />
            </MenuContainer>
            :   
            <MenuContainer  onPress={onLike}  >
            <IconButtonU iconName="favorite"
                 source={require('../../Assets/Images/Tabs/ic_favorite_outline.png')}
                 />
                 </MenuContainer>
                 }


            <LikeNumber>
            좋아요{' '}
            {singlePost?.Likers.length }
            </LikeNumber>


            </Container>

            );
            };

            export default Explain;
```